# Is it possible to port forward traffic from VPN server to one of clients?

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, nat, upnp

I'm having a problem with NAT type in one of games. I cannot port forward my home network cause ISP blocks any traffic anyway, so the only solution would be to have a VPN server of mine.

Everything works as intended except for CoD Black Ops 3.

Lobbies don't prioritize VPN networks, so me and my friends end up getting Moderate NAT type and we can't join to each other.

So my thought would be to somehow connect to my VPN server, have my traffic relayed through server's network and then let my friends try to connect to me via server's IP. I tried to explain more or less what I need on the picture below.

[image: scheme]

Is that achievable on such configuration?

Comment: I think this has been answered elsewhere (but in short, it's just regular DNAT "port forwarding")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your VPN server gives you a publicly routable IP address for the virtual interface inside the VPN tunnel, then you shouldn't have to do any port forwarding. You should just tell your friends to connect to the public address you get via VPN, rather than your home LAN private address or your home gateway NAT's public address.

If you're organizing games via a game "lobby" server run by the game publisher, you need to make sure that your game software is registering your VPN-given public address (not your private LAN address or your home gateway NAT's public address) with the game "lobby" servers. If the game software doesn't let you control which address gets registered, you may want to see if you can set your VPN to be a "full tunnel" VPN. "Full tunnel" means all traffic to/from your machine must go through the tunnel. Having a full tunnel VPN connection up would make it impossible for your game software to talk to the game lobby server directly (i.e. outside of the VPN tunnel), so only your VPN-provided public address should be visible to the game lobby server.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Going with full tunnel seems to be working